# How to add a warning message on a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

So I want a Warning message box on a batch file, but I tried everything to do, Like: `VBWarning / VBWarningQuery`
But it wont work!
Here is the Code:

```
@echo off

call :MsgBox "Are you Sure you want to uninstall? You might accidnentally uninstall like: Uninstall Save Files, Batch Files, Folders, and Files. Are you REALLY SURE You want to do this?"  "VBYesNo+VBQuestion" "You REALLY Sure?"
if errorlevel 7 (
    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
) else if errorlevel 6 (
    start uninstall.bat
)
exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
setlocal enableextensions
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
>"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```

"VBYesNo+VBQuestion", to -> a Warning Command: "VBYesNo+Warning".

Comment: The button constants, other than `VBYesNo` _(Show yes, no buttons [Value `4`])_, are `VBCritical`, _(Show critical message [Value `16`])_, `VBQuestion`, _(Show query message [Value `32`])_, `VBExclamation`, _(Show warning message [Value `48`])_, and `VBInformation`, _(Show information message [Value `64`])_. There is no `VBWarning` constant so I'm going to assume you're looking for `VBExclamation`. You don't need to use the constants however, you can use the values, adding them for multiple button criteria. So for `VBYesNo` + `VBExclamation`, you could use the value `52`, i.e. (`4` + `48`).

Comment: Do you know how much harm is produced by the command line `taskkill /f /im cmd.exe`? This command causes a forced __kill__ of __all__ currently running `cmd.exe` processes. Many programs call in background `cmd.exe`. Many batch files modify registry values or contents of files. They are all __killed__ by this command line without giving them the chance to gracefully terminate themselves after finishing their tasks. Such a batch file would be never used on my PC as I don't want file and registry corruptions caused by a batch file using such a command line.

Answer (score 0):

There is no ***vbWarning*** in vbscript

There is **vbExclamtion** :

---

Your code can be written like this :

```
@echo off
Title Asking YES Or NO + VbExclamtion
call :MsgBox "Are you Sure you want to uninstall? You might accidnentally uninstall like: Uninstall Save Files,Batch Files, Folders, and Files. Are you REALLY SURE You want to do this ?"  "VBYesNo+vbExclamation" "You REALLY Sure ?"
if errorlevel 7 (
    Exit
) else if errorlevel 6 (
    echo start uninstall.bat
)
pause & exit /b

:MsgBox prompt type title
setlocal enableextensions
set "tempFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%%random%vbs.tmp"
>"%tempFile%" echo(WScript.Quit msgBox("%~1",%~2,"%~3") & cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%tempFile%"
set "exitCode=%errorlevel%" & del "%tempFile%" >nul 2>nul
endlocal & exit /b %exitCode%
```